# How do I use a Controller which is in a Class Library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have controllers in a class library but I can't work out how to get the main project to recognise them. The main project has a reference to my class library. Do I need to register them somewhere?

I want to use both Controllers and ApiControllers.

**EDIT:**

Route config - unchanged from creating the project:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Dashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

WebApi config, again unchanged:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Controller I'm attempting to get working first:

```
public class UIController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult StartMenu()
    {
        StartMenu menu = StartMenuFactory.Get();

        return PartialView(menu);
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult Explorer()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Page/
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I created a Test.cshtml within a UI folder inside Views in my main project. Explorer.cshtml and StartMenu.cshtml are within Shared inside Views.

Comment: Have you added the namespace in the `using` section in the class you want to use them in?

Comment: Yes, both 4.5. I haven't added a `using` as I want my route/webapi configs to pick them up and use them.

Comment: Is your main project an MVC4 or MVC5 Project?

Comment: MVC5 using VS 2013 Express

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your controller class name end with "Controller", this is mandatory.

What you are doing should work, the controller factory does this:

> ... the default factory uses a type cache
>   internally. The type cache is implemented in the
>   ControllerTypeCache class. During the application initialization, the
>   ControllerTypeCache class uses .NET reflection to enumerate all the
>   **referenced** assemblies and explores them looking for publicly exposed
>   controller types. A controller type is any referenced type that passes
>   the following test:

```
static bool IsControllerType(Type t)
{
     return
        t != null &&
        t.IsPublic &&
        t.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
        !t.IsAbstract &&
        typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t);
}
```

From: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/asp.net-mvc-controllers-and-conventions/

This means that a simple reference to an assembly with your controllers should suffice.

If you controller satisfies these rules you should be ok.

Comment: Yep, it starts: `public class UIController : Controller` so it should match all of these conditions, right? There's definitely a reference in my main project too.

Comment: Are you getting a 404 for urls like `http://localhost/UI/someUIControlleraction` and are you using the default route?

Comment: I get a 404 when I go to `http://localhost/UI/Test`. See edits in the main post for some code.

Comment: You might be using an out of date version of the cache, make a change to global.asax so that the cache is invalidated and try again: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/403529

Comment: No dice. Everything gives me a 404 - starting to think there's a problem elsewhere but I have no idea where..

Comment: @Jon Just tried creating a project from scratch, adding a class library with a controller, referencing it from the web project and it works, no need to do anything else, including messing with the namespaces in the route. I tried with MVC3

Comment: Yep, I created a new project from scratch and it just works. No idea what was wrong with the other one, I have combed the files in both projects and I see no discernible difference. I'm getting some real quirky behaviour since upgrading to MVC5.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the API controllers is going to be different from the solution for regular MVC due to a number of factors.  See the following for information on how to handle Web API controllers: [using external web api controllers](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/using-controllers-from-an-external-assembly-in-asp-net-web-api/)

Comment: Do you know if this is still the case for MVC5?