# A 404 not found error in ajax Get request for a class library project

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, url, http-status-code-404

I am making a simple **class library** project where i make an **AJAX** Get Request in HTML file to Get Data from server ( returned in a method inside a c# class ) .

**HTML script field where the AJAX call** :

```
$( function () {

    $('#btnSend').click(function () {

        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "./Employee/Getdata",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (response) {

                console.log(response);

            },

            failure: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("HTTP Status: " + jqXHR.status + "; Error Text: " + jqXHR.responseText); // Display error message  
            }

        })

    })
});
```

**C# called class  :**

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 

public class Employee 
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public List<Employee> GetData()
    {
        var empList = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee { ID=1, Name="Hamdi"},
            new Employee { ID=2, Name="Tester"}
        };
        return empList ;
    } 

}
```

The problem is that a **404 NOT found** error is shown in console tells me the Url is wrong, Although it works fine in **MVC** project with the same url, in the case this class follows the path: **Controllers/HomeController/Employee.cs**

I searched a lot but all examples are **MVC** or **webforms** projects, which are not my case,  What can be the right URL then?

Comment: Wait, if you're not using MVC or webforms, what *are* you using?

Comment: @GabrielLuci    Actually i want to use it in a class library project , which hasn't MVC project hierarchy and doesn't support .aspx files types .

Comment: So what is handling the HTTP requests?

Comment: @GabrielLuci That's the point finally , how to do it inside a class library project

Comment: I think you will have to make assumptions about the parent project. You won't be able to make a class that will work in any type of project. But you can do it if you assume the parent project is ASP.NET MVC, for example. You have to pick what you will support.

Comment: @GabrielLuci thanks ! it would be awesome if you can explain more to find an outlet for this problem , since all resources are very limited

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you assume that the parent project will always be an ASP.NET MVC project. But you will need to make some modifications to your class. A good explanation of how ASP.NET finds controller classes is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21705390/1202807).

In short, rename the class to `EmployeeController` and the file to `EmployeeController.cs` and make it inherit from `Controller`:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
```

As long as the parent project has the default routes configured, it should find this controller in the library and route requests to it when a request is made to `/Employee/GetData`

If you want to change the route, you can use attribute routing, but that also assumes that the main project has enabled attribute routing.

```
[RoutePrefix("Employee")]
public class EmployeeController : Controller
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [HttpGet("Data")]
    public List<Employee> GetData()
    {
        var empList = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee { ID=1, Name="Hamdi"},
            new Employee { ID=2, Name="Tester"}
        };
        return empList ;
    }
}
```

That should make it work with `/Employee/Data`.

Comment: thanks , that would be a step to the solution . I released the Url path is known when i mention folders or classnames.cs in the url but it doesn't resolve  actions inside controller class . The main problem i see that no Routing-configuration  file exists in the class library project to define the url path , should i add one ? and how to make the project recognize it (the configuration) to resolve the path ?

Comment: NOTICE : my main project is a class library ,  not an MVC project which calls a class library containing controllers . The class library itself should resolve the path

Comment: The main project will always have control of the routing. A class library can't force a specific route. If you make the change I suggest *and* the main project has the default routes setup, then it will be accessible with `/Employee/GetData`.

Comment: I also updated my answer to include using attribute routing to suggest a different route, but that also depends on the main project enabling attribute routing.

Answer (score 0):

Employee should be a controller and GetData should be an IActionResult.. Aside from that the correct URL in javascript would be:

> url: "/Employee/Getdata"

. If you use atribute based routing the url in the controller would be:

> [HttpGet(“Employee/Getdata”)]

Comment: I am not working in MVC project , the project is a class library

Comment: No that didn't work , that should be necessary another url . as i mentioned that worked fine with an MVC project